# Display:none when rotating smartphone

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I'm currently making a website for mobile devices. In style.css I got

```
#mobilepicture {
display: none;
}

#stockpicture {
float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -65px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

This is a part of the mobile.css:

```
#stockpicture {
display: none;
}
#mobilepicture {
...
}
```

When switching over to mobile.css everything seems okey (mobilepicture is displayed, stockpicture display:none), until I tilt my phone sideways. When I do that the stockpicture changes to be displayed again. I know it's because of the selector in the beginning:

index.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)"  />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
</head> 
<!-- Head end-->
<!-- Body start-->
<body>
    <!-- stockpicture-->
    <div id="stockpicture">
            <img src="images/stockpicture.png" alt="stockpicture"/>
        </div>
    <!-- stockpicture end-->
    <!-- Start Container-->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Content start -->
        <div id="contentindex">
        <!-- Mobile picture-->
            <div id="mobilepicture">
            <img src="images/mobilepicture.png" alt="mobilepicture" width="200" height="300"/>
        </div>
        <!-- Mobile end -->
            <h2> Home </h2>
            <p>Snippet.</p> </div>

  <!-- end .container --></div>
```

Is there any other way to solve this? or possibly deny the browser to rotate?

Cheers
JJ

Comment: Can you try adding more conditions, such as height?

Comment: Tried that, stopped loading the CSS alltogether

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding in orientation to your media query?

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, try stripping it all back so you can see what's working and what isn't. For a start I would have one stylesheet with multiple media queries in as this will help performance - [Single vs multiple stylesheets in responsive web design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660241/single-vs-multiple-stylesheets-in-responsive-web-design)

Then strip it all out, and replace with a nice simple media query that does something simple like change the background colour of the body for example.

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
    body {
        background: yellow;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Once you know your actually running the media queries properly you should be able to troubleshoot much more easily.

Comment: in index php: 


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)"  />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />

 --- other stuff

    <div id="stockpicture">
                    <img src="images/stockpicture.png" alt="stockpic"/>
                </div>

Comment: <!-- More stuff -->
    <!-- Mobile picture, hidden in style.css-->
                    <div id="mobilepicture">
                    <img src="images/mobilepicture.png" alt="mobpic" width="200" height="300"/>
                </div>

Style.css:

    /*Stockpicture*/ 
    #stockpicture {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     top: -65px;
     left: 100px;
     }
/* mobile picture*/
    #mobilepicture {
     display: none;
     }


Mobile.css:
<!-- Stockpicture -->

    #stockpicture {
     display: none;
     }
    
    <!-- mobile picture -->

Comment: #mobilepicture {
  float:left;
  clear: both;
  padding: 40px 15px 95px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
 }


The mobile picture is wrapped inside the content box (image) together with a paragrap (which shouldn't be a problem), the stockpicture overlaps the content box. You need more than that?

Comment: Could you just put the relevant HTML in an edit on the question?