# Do I put this meta tag in for media queries?

Tags: css, media

A css question about meta tags in head

```
<link rel="stylesheet"media="screen and <min width npx)" href="assets/stylesheets/large.css">
```

Does the code below still need to go in?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="large.css">
```

Comment: Your question is _very_ unclear.  What don't you understand?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if I need to put both <link rel="stylesheet" href="large.css"> and  <link rel="stylesheet"media="screen and <min width npx)" href="assets/stylesheets/large.css"> 
Does the second link only reference the media query in css, or does it cover linking the entire stylesheet?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using multiple stylesheets rather than just using one?

Comment: If `large.css` is the same stylesheet as `assets/stylesheets/large.css`, then you need only one. If they are different stylesheets, then you need both! You have errors in your media attribute though, and it needs a space  between attributes.

Comment: Couldn't you just try it with and without and see?

Comment: @Quentin It could still work that way, but not necessarily be the correct way to do it.

Comment: @VincenzoAlexander WHat do you mean by "the correct way" then?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use multiple stylesheets for responsive design. This just creates more HTTP requests which are not necessary. [Read here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660241/single-vs-multiple-stylesheets-in-responsive-web-design)

Instead, use media queries within your CSS file. Like so:

```
@media (min-width: 10em) and (max-width: 20em) {
    /* responsive styles go here */
}
```

Read here for more on how to use these: http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are a feature of the CSS language within a single stylesheet.

You do not need to change the `<link>` tag at all.

The `<link media="...">` tag is only useful if you have an entire stylesheet of rules that should only be applied under a specific media query; this allows the browser to skip downloading the file if the media query doesn't match (saving bandwidth)