# Hiding the unwanted part of a CSS corner ribbon without rendering my navigation useless?

Tags: css, overflow, z-index, overlap

I've created a corner ribbon for a site as per [this tutorial](http://unindented.org/articles/2009/10/github-ribbon-using-css-transforms/)

I seem to run into trouble when trying to put it in the top right corner, though, as the ribbon now extends the overall width of the site, and is visible all the way to the right when you scroll the page horizontally.

This is pretty easy to fix by placing the ribbon inside a wrapper with `position: absolute`, `top:0`, `right:0` and `overflow: hidden`.

BUT this leads to another problem, namely the wrapper now overlaps my mobile menu (based on the select tag), rendering it unclickable. The ribbon needs to be on the top, well, because it's a ribbon, and it wouldn't do any harm either, if not for the forementioned wrapper.

So, my question is, is there any other way to hide the 'leftover' part of the ribbon on the right? Preferably something that wouldn't mess my navigation...

Comment: Is there any way I can get a link to inspect your problem?

Comment: It's a client's site in production unfortunately, so I'm unable to provide you with the original link. I could end up reconstructing a simpler version on jsfiddle if I don't figure this out otherwise. I'll let you know if this happens.

Comment: Creating a small, reproducible version of the problem is always a good idea

Comment: A link/ fiddle is indeed needed in order to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click though the ribbon:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Explanation of click-though: [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Apply to mobile only: [Creating a mobile web page with different css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317038/creating-a-mobile-web-page-with-different-css-style)