# GoogleChrome imports CSS from IE10 @import hack

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10

The following CSS is being used to add IE specific styles. But GoogleChrome is downloading them in the network console as well. Why?

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
    <!--[if IE]>
    <link href="/Style-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
      /* if IE 10 */
      @import url('/Style-ie.css') screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none);
    </style>
    
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out the second answer given here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e)

Comment: Hmm.. in fact that one "solved" my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311235/why-do-all-browsers-download-all-css-files-even-for-media-types-they-dont-sup .